# Add own Application to the Win10 Lockscreen

Tags: .net, windows-10, customization, lockscreen

**BACKGROUND:** *I was wondering, whether it is possible to write a .NET-application which can be added to the Windows10 Lockscreen.*
*I am travelling a lot with the train and I would like to show the next departure times on my lockscreen (combined with other more or less useful information)...*

As you may know, it is possible to add a (predefined) app to "customize" the lockscreen, e.g. with the calendar-app or the weather-app:
[image]

---

I now want to add a custom application to the lockscreen. Is this possible? And if so, how? Do I have some kind of reserved canvas, into which I can draw? Do I have to provide some XAML-control, which will be embedded?

How do I "register" my application after having written it, so that I can use it from the windows settings? Do I have to sign it with some special certificate? ....

---

And yes, I have done some research before, but nearly all posts were about customization on a Android or WinPhone-Lockscreen or ended with the answer, that the Windows8-API for the lockscreen was not yet released. *(I do not know, how much the Win10 lockscreen differs from the Win8 one)*

---

**Edit №1:** I guess, I could render a lockscreen-image multiple times per second and replace the default lockscreen with my rendered image, but that is comparable to drinking a bottle of bleach....